# Classification issue

Tags: c, max, classification, min

I have an array of struct with 4 variables.

```
records[i].time
records[i].xaxis
records[i].yaxis
records[i].zaxis
```

Where `i` will the index of records. Whose maximum is `n`. In the above, `records[i].time` is ordered in ascending order of time in array and is in milliseconds. I have to find the

```
maximum of records[i].xaxis
minimum of records[i].xaxis
maximum of records[i].yaxis
minimum of records[i].yaxis
maximum of records[i].zaxis
minimum of records[i].zaxis
```

for a group of each second in `records[i].time`, find the difference (maximum-minimum) and assign to another struct

```
neighbour[k].difx
neighbour[k].dify
neighbour[k].difz
```

where k will be the index of each group.
Here is what I have done so far

```
i = 0; //initialize counter
int k = 1; // second
int j; //internal counter
float minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz; // min and max values of the other 3 fields of the struct records
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++){
//initialize min and max 
    maxx = records[i].xaxis;
    minx = records[i].xaxis;
    maxy = records[i].yaxis;
    miny = records[i].yaxis;
    maxz = records[i].zaxis;
    minz = records[i].zaxis;
    //start looking for the maximum and the minimum
    for( j = i; j < n; j++){
        if(records[j].time < k * 1000){//check only for values within the desired time period
            if( records[j].xaxis > maxx ){
                maxx = records[j].xaxis;
            }
            if( records[j].xaxis < minx ){
                minx = records[j].xaxis;
            }
            if( records[j].yaxis > maxy ){
                maxy = records[j].yaxis;
            }
            if( records[j].yaxis < miny ){
                miny = records[j].yaxis;
            }
            if( records[j].zaxis > maxz ){
                maxz = records[j].zaxis;
            }
            if( records[j].zaxis < minz ){
                minz = records[j].zaxis;
            }
        }
    }//once the proper values are found save the difference between max and min.
    neighbour[i].difx = maxx-minx;
    neighbour[i].dify = maxy-miny;
    neighbour[i].difz = maxz-minz;  
    k++;    
}
```

Results i am getting are different. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the question?  Are you facing any error?

Comment: My understanding of this question is you're trying to define some kind of bounding box around values for each 1 second of data.  It would help if you told us whether the records are ordered by time.

Comment: Voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have said. I am assuming that *records[i].time* is in ascending order. Then the code will become.

```
i = 0; //initialize counter
int k = 1; // second
float minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz; // min and max values of the other 3 fields of the struct records

//initialize min and max 
maxx = records[0].xaxis;
minx = records[0].xaxis;
maxy = records[0].yaxis;
miny = records[0].yaxis;
maxz = records[0].zaxis;
minz = records[0].zaxis; 

for ( i = 1; i < n; i++){
//start looking for the maximum and the minimum
    if(records[i].time <= k * 1000){//check only for values within the desired time period
        if( records[i].xaxis > maxx ){
            maxx = records[i].xaxis;
        }
        if( records[i].xaxis < minx ){
            minx = records[i].xaxis;
        }
        if( records[i].yaxis > maxy ){
            maxy = records[i].yaxis;
        }
        if( records[i].yaxis < miny ){
            miny = records[i].yaxis;
        }
        if( records[i].zaxis > maxz ){
            maxz = records[i].zaxis;
        }
        if( records[i].zaxis < minz ){
            minz = records[i].zaxis;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        neighbour[k-1].difx = maxx-minx;
        neighbour[k-1].dify = maxy-miny;
        neighbour[k-1].difz = maxz-minz;  
        k++;    
        maxx = records[i].xaxis;
        minx = records[i].xaxis;
        maxy = records[i].yaxis;
        miny = records[i].yaxis;
        maxz = records[i].zaxis;
        minz = records[i].zaxis; 
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly for the x and y, but it gives incomprehensible answers for z. I have checked my data and they are ok. Any ideas?

Comment: I found it. A small typo, both in the code I provided and the one you gave me back.